# Find out about arguments passed to functions

Tags: prefix-argument, arguments

When I press `C-h k C-SPC`, Emacs shows me:

> C-SPC runs the command set-mark-command (found in global-map), which
>   is an interactive compiled Lisp function.
>
> It is bound to C-@, C-SPC.
>
> (set-mark-command ARG)
>
> Set the mark where point is, and activate it; or jump to the mark.
>   Setting the mark also alters the region, which is the text between
>   point and mark; this is the closest equivalent in Emacs to what some
>   editors call the "selection".
>
> With no prefix argument, set the mark at point, and push the old mark
>   position on local mark ring.  Also push the new mark on global mark
>   ring, if the previous mark was set in another buffer.
>
> When Transient Mark Mode is off, immediately repeating this command
>   activates ‘transient-mark-mode’ temporarily.
>
> With prefix argument (e.g., C-u C-SPC), jump to the mark, and set the
>   mark from position popped off the local mark ring (this does not
>   affect the global mark ring).  Use C-x C-@ to jump to a mark popped
>   off the global mark ring (see ‘pop-global-mark’).
>
> If ‘set-mark-command-repeat-pop’ is non-nil, repeating the C-SPC
>   command with no prefix argument pops the next position off the local
>   (or global) mark ring and jumps there.
>
> With C-u C-u as prefix argument, unconditionally set mark where point
>   is, even if ‘set-mark-command-repeat-pop’ is non-nil.
>
> Novice Emacs Lisp programmers often try to use the mark for the wrong
>   purposes.  See the documentation of ‘set-mark’ for more information.
>
> [back]

I don't see where it says what it chooses for `ARG`. Apparently, `set-mark-command` needs an argument because evaluating `(set-mark-command)` results in an error.

How do I find out about the argument passed to `set-mark-command` when I hit `C-SPC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set-mark-command` (as the name suggests) is meant to be used as a *command* and not called as a *function*.  For that reason, the docstring talks about the interactive uses rather than the case where you call it from Elisp code.

Once you're familiar with the "universal prefix argument" in Elisp, you can mostly decode the above docstring and guess that ARG will be `nil` if there's "no prefix argument" and will be `(16)` when the user pressed "C-u C-u as prefix argument".

To find out in detail you'd have to look at the definition of the `set-mark-command` function, more specifically at its *interactive spec*:

```
[...]
(interactive "P")
[...]
```

which says that the first argument of the function (i.e. ARG) will take the value of the variable `current-prefix-arg` (which holds the previous value of `prefix-arg`, that variable being set by the prefix commands `universal-argument` and `digit-argument`), as documented (not quite precisely enough) in the docstring of `interactive`:

```
[...]
P -- Prefix arg in raw form.  Does not do I/O.
[...]
```

Comment: So do key bindings never pass anything except the prefix argument to the function they're bound to? And then you only need to check what the interactive line passes to the function?

Comment: Of course not: the docstring of `interactive` lists all kinds of other things you can pass to commands this way,  E.g. `C-x C-f` (aka `find-file`) passes the file name (after prompting for it in the minibuffer).

Comment: Ah, so the interactive line is evaluated when the function is called via a key binding or via `M-x`? Emacs runs `find-file-read-args` from `find-file`'s interactive line and the result is passed to `find-file` when it is called right afterwards?

Comment: @UTF-8: Exactly: the `interactive` spec is used to build the list of arguments that are then passed to the function.